# JQuery Sum Text Input Values If  Select Dropdown Value Equals DIV Value

Tags: jquery, sum

[My Example on JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/nspinelli/CJMYK/15/)
I am trying to sum values from a table based on check numbers that can be selected in a select box.  Here is what I have so far - If someone could please point me into the right direction that would be great.  Thanks in advance.

For this example, if you choose check 1234 for both selections in table two I want to sum those input fields and print it out in table one in the row having that check number.

If you choose check 1234 in row one it will only sum that value and print it out in table one in the row having that check number.

I have been trying to figure this out all day and can not come up with a solution.  If anyone could help me out or atleast point me in the right direction I would be much appreciative.

```
<table id="acctRec">
<tr>
    <td>Check Number</td>
    <td>Amount Paid</td>
    <td>Applied</td>
    <td>Variance</td>
</tr>
<tr class="all">
    <td class="org">1234</td>
    <td>300</td>
    <td class="totalApplied"></td>
    <td></td>
</tr>
<tr class="all">
    <td class="org">4321</td>
    <td>400</td>
    <td class="totalApplied"></td>
    <td></td>
</tr>
</table>
<table>
<tr>
    <th>Name</th>
    <th> Amount Due</th>
    <th colspan="2">Applied</th>
    <th>Check Num</th>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>First Name</td>
<td>400</td>
<td><input class="checkbox" type="checkbox"></td>
<td><input type="text" class="amount"></td>
<td><select class="checknum">
<option></option>
<option value="1234">1234</option>
<option value="4321">4321</option>
</select>
</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>First Name</td>
<td>500</td>
<td><input class="checkbox" type="checkbox"></td>
<td><input type="text" class="amount"></td>
<td><select class="checknum">
<option></option>
<option value="1234">1234</option>
<option value="4321">4321</option>
</select>
</td>
</tr>

</table>
```

And the Jquery...

```
$('table input[type="checkbox"]').bind('click change', function() {
var input = $(this).closest('td').next('td').find('input');
var invoice = $('.invoice');
if ($(this).is(':checked')) {
    var amount = $(this).closest('td').prev('td').text();
    var holdback = '1';
    var newtot = amount * holdback;
    input.val(newtot);
} else {
    input.val('0.00');
}
});

$('select').bind('keyup change', function() {
$('.org').each(function() {
    var all = $(this).text();
    //alert(all);
});
$('.checknum').each(function() {
    var sel = $(this).val();
    //alert(sel);
    if (all=sel) {
        //Found check number in table 1, insert sum value
        alert(all);
    } 
    else {
        //No check number, append row to table 1

    }

});

});
```

Comment: The `Check Num` is like an ID? You can set a data attr on `tr` element. `<tr data-chk="1234">`

Comment: @DavidRodrigues : Yes.  The check number is pulled from a database and so the list of all the check numbers will be the same as all the options in the select box.  How would could I sum just using the data attr and append the sum to the appropriate cell in table one?

Answer (score 0):

please check i have updated the code.
http://jsfiddle.net/CJMYK/20/

```
var holdback = 1; // changed from '1' to one since you are muiltiplying, it should be number not char.
var newtot = amount * holdback;
```

Comment: Thanks for the input, but I still don't know how to sum the amounts by check number. I want to sum all of the values in the second table by check number and place the sum in the first table by it's cooresponding check number.

Comment: can you please give an example what you are exactly expecting ?

Comment: In the second table if you choose a check number from the select box I want to have the sum of all the input boxes with that check number to show up in the first table in the same row as the check number.

Comment: Also, removing the single quotation marks results in an error when I use values less than one.